# Is there any reason for Test-NetConnection to be slow in connecting to the loopback address?

Tags: powershell, networking

I've got some odd network latency with TCP connections that I'm trying to figure out. In my testing I'm using both **Test-NetConnection** (alias tnc), and System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient. The System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient library creates a connection in just a few milliseconds to external servers and to the loopback address. When I use TNC however, I get vastly different results from different machines, even for the loopback address.  TNC for the loopback on the fastest machines is 400 milliseconds and 9 seconds on the worst machines. Note, I'm only talking about successful TNC commands without any PING timeout or other warnings. These results seem useful to me in terms of diagnosing an application behavior that is coincident with the TNC behavior. On machines that are 9 seconds to TNC the loopback it is also slow to make an application connection. This is why I am trying to figure out why TNC is so slow to connect to the loopback.

```
Measure-Command {tnc 127.0.0.1 -port 445 | Out-Default} | ft TotalMilliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not explain why it is slow but, here a faster version.  This could vary from computer to computer.

```
$HomeIP = Measure-Command {tnc 127.0.0.1 -port 445 | Out-Default} 
$localhost = Measure-Command {tnc localhost -port 445 | Out-Default} 
$Compname =  Measure-Command {tnc $env:COMPUTERNAME -port 445 | Out-Default}

Write-host "127.0.0.1 takes $($HomeIP.TotalMilliseconds) Milliseconds"
write-host "localhost takes $($localhost.TotalMilliseconds) Milliseconds"
write-host "`$env:COMPUTERNAME takes $($Compname.TotalMilliseconds) Milliseconds"


127.0.0.1 takes 4741.1638 Milliseconds
localhost takes 1197.1043 Milliseconds
$env:COMPUTERNAME takes 269.6711 Milliseconds
```